# "他の場所や国の建物や景色などを見ること" = "Seeing buildings, scenery, etc. in other places and countries."?

Tags: translation, particles, parsing

Recently, I came across this sentence on a Japanese learning website.

> 他の場所や国の建物や景色などを見ること

I've learned that (AやBやCなど) means something like (A,B,C,etc).
However, both Google Translate and DeepL translate the sentence as

> Seeing buildings, scenery, etc., in other places or countries

So I translated this as

> About seeing other places, buildings inside the country, landscape, etc

I couldn't find any exceptional rule to (AやBなど) grammar. Either both translators make the same mistake (which is unlikely) or I am unaware of a certain exception to the grammar structure.

Answer (score 3):

> {[他の(場所や国)]の(建物や景色など)}を見ること

You can parse it as above. You are seeing 建物や景色など and the の tells you what kind of 建物や景色など i.e., ones in other places and countries.